# RSS Feed as a list using XMLStore in Sencha Touch 2

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I am trying to show a feed as a list. When I try doing this with reader type as json, it works fine. However, with type as xml, it doesn't work. I get an exception:

**Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/xml: "http://feeds.feedburner.com/TechCrunch/?_dc=1345109660600&page=1&start=0&limit=25&callback=Ext.data.JsonP.callback1".* 
*Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <**

```
Ext.define('TestViews.view.RSSFeedView', {
    requires:[
        'TestViews.view.CommonTitleBar',
        'TestViews.view.CommonContainer',
        'TestViews.locale.MsgResource'
    ],
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    xtype: 'Test-rssfeedview',
    id:'rssFeedView',
    config: {
        fullscreen: true,
        layout: {
            type: 'vbox'
        },
        autoDestroy: true,
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'Test-commontitlebar',
                title: 'RSS Feed Component'
            },
            {
                xtype: 'list',
                id: 'rssFeedList',
                title : 'RSS Feed View',

                                    itemId:"testList",
                                    onItemDisclosure: true,
                                    itemTpl: '{title}',
                flex: 1,
               store:{
                   model: "TestViews.model.RSSFeedViewModel",
                   autoLoad: true,
                   implicitIncludes: true,
                   proxy: {
                       type: 'jsonp',
                        url: 'http://feeds.feedburner.com/TechCrunch/',                          
                       reader: {
                           type: 'xml',
                           root: 'channel',
                            record: 'channel'
                           }
                       }
               },
                width: '100%',                    
                autoDestroy: true,
            }
        ]
    }
})
```

Model:

```
enter Ext.define('TestViews.model.RSSFeedViewModel', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

config: {
    fields: [
        'title','description'
    ]
}});
```

Can you tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: you use proxy type jsonp so it must expect json as response that's why you get error.even if you want to use xml then try reader type ajax.

Comment: Thank you naresh for the response. However, proxy type can either be: Ajax - sends requests to a server on the same domain or JsonP - to send requests to a server on a different domain according to me. So, is there anything else that could be wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot read XML as JSONP. Have a look at how JSONP works:

The Same Origin Policy prevents any Browser to load data from different URLS. To work around this, you can add a -Tag to your DOM with a src Attribute contains the URL of the data you want to load.

But after that, you have the data (RSS feed data in your case) between the start and end of this new script tag. The Browser starts to interpret it as JavaScript and - bam! *Unexpected token <* ... And thats correct, because it is not JavaScript, it's RSS.

Summary: **JSONP can just be used to load JavaScript from another URL!**

Solution:
You can wrap the RSS data as a String in a JSON. Google API helps you here:

```
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?q=URL&v=1.0&num=10&output=json-in-script
```

This gives you a JSON object which contains the converted feed data. Search the API Docs for the arguments, the really help you.

Credits: http://www.alaafu.com/rssreader-sencha/#favorites/first